# When does the Lando comic from Marvel take place?

Tags: star-wars

Marvel Comics released a well-received comic miniseries called *Lando*, set in the Disney *Star Wars* canon. I am aware that it takes place after the Battle of Yavin, but is there an exact date?

Comment: I'm guessing they won't pin themselves down to a specific date. It's just some time between 0ABY and 3ABY.

Answer (score 2):

Marvel have released a statement confirming that the new comic serials (Star Wars, Darth Vader, Leia, Han Solo) are set between the end of Star Wars: A New Hope and Star Wars: The Empire Strikes back. That places them **firmly between 0ABY and 3ABY.**

> It’s very much a team book and we’ve got all the main players here.
> Luke, Han, Leia, Chewie, the droids, and Darth Vader all get big
> moments in this first arc, and that’s our core cast going forward. I
> do want to be able to use Obi-Wan Kenobi. I’ve always liked the old
> Ben Kenobi version of Obi-Wan, so we will see him in some capacity.
>
> Story wise, I think our book is driven in some big way by Luke and by
> the pretty interesting spot we find him in at this period in the
> timeline. **You look at the gap between Episodes IV and V and there’s
> quite a bit that happens off screen that we get to explore.**
>
> <sub><sup>[SDCC 2014: INSIDE MARVEL’S NEW STAR WARS COMICS – EXCLUSIVE](http://www.starwars.com/news/sdcc-2014-inside-marvels-new-star-wars-comics-exclusive)</sup></sub>

That being said, where Lando is concerned, his absence from the first Star Wars film would seem to give them additional latitude. It's certainly possible the writers could go back farther than 0ABY without his *personal history* impacting on the main canon. I would assume if they did so, they'd make it clear in the actual story.

> “Before Cloud City, before his glorious Death Star run,” continues
> Soule, “Lando Calrissian was just a man trying to make his way through
> an uncaring universe determined not to recognize that he was
> undeniably the coolest man in the galaxy. But Lando’s got a plan to
> change all that… and it starts with the deal of a lifetime.”
>
> <sub><sup>[LANDO #1 COMING IN JULY FROM MARVEL – EXCLUSIVE!](http://www.starwars.com/news/lando-1-coming-in-july-from-marvel-exclusive)</sup></sub>